# Convert yes/no column to 1/0 in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Is there a quick and easy way to create new a column which takes a column that has yes/no values and then changes it to 1/0?

Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you can compute this column in Power Query by adding a new conditional column, removing the original column and renaming the new column.

Or you can do a replacement rule, see following minimal example that you can paste in as a blank query:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WikwtVorViVbyywdTMC6ycCwA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,each [Column1], each if _[Column1] = "Yes" then 1 else 0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```